# Gmail API How to deal with non existent threadId

Tags: gmail-api, google-workspace

I am working on a solution to restore a message back into a Gmail mailbox as close to the original message as possible. I downloaded the message and its RAW content. I was to then insert this message back into the mailbox using the Insert call of the Gmail API. If the message is deleted after the initial download, I am able to insert the message back with the original message Id. But if this email was part of a mail thread, and the entire original thread was deleted, when I try to insert the message back with the original ThreadId, I get the following 404 error:

```
Google.GoogleApiException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The service gmail has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is NotFound. Requested entity was not found.
  Source=Google.Apis
  StackTrace:
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ParseResponse>d__35.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at CVGmailProvider.DataAccessor.MessageAccessor.InsertMessage(Message message) in SomePath
 
  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest<TResponse>.ParseResponse(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage)
    Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest<TResponse>.Execute()
```

Is there a way to preserve / create a thread with the original Thread Id? It is quite expensive to have to create a new Thread Id and then map all of the other messages in the thread with the new Thread Id.

How come we can preserve the original message Id, but not the Thread Id.

Any recommendations / solutions?